# How to find new nodes with overpass?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I was trying to retrieve certain nodes via Overpass API that are newly created within a defined time frame (or at least since a certain point in time). So far I only managed to end up with basically this query:

```
[out:json][timeout:30];
node
    [amenity=atm]
    ({{bbox}})
    (newer:"2018-04-01T00:00:00Z");
out;
```

However this also shows nodes that have been updated since that timestamp but might have been created several years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a version filter and you're all set. New nodes will have version = 1.

```
[out:json][timeout:30];
node
    [amenity=atm]
    ({{bbox}})
    (newer:"2018-04-01T00:00:00Z")
    (if:version() == 1);
out meta;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much this is exactly what I needed. Can you suggest some resources I should read to get better at OverpassQL? So far these resources have been my rescues: 
* https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API
* https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide
* https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example
* https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE:Overpass_API/Beispielsammlung
* https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL
* https://help.openstreetmap.org/tags/overpass

Comment: You can basically leave out the "Language Guide" in this list, it's no longer maintained.